# What do you do when package requires old version of a core library, like SSL?

Tags: arch-linux, dependencies, google-earth

My Google Earth recently stopped working. It just crashes when I try to start it. I tried to rebuild it and get an SSL 1.0 missing dependency. Of course, SSL is now 1.1 so there is no SSL 1.0 on the machine. I assume this is probably the reason Google Earth is crashing: the system's SSL has been upgraded to 1.1 and Google Earth requires 1.0.

So how do I handle this situation?

---

Note, I eventually solved this problem by a combination of various system upgrades, restarting the machine and re-installing Google Earth. Somewhere in the chain of dependencies, the problem got noticed and solved by somebody.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19214/libssl-and-libcrypto-backward-compatible may interest you

Answer (score 1):

For RPM-based distros, you'll want to install the [`compat-openssl10`](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=compat-openssl10) package.

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason using older OpenSSL is not possible, you might want to consider using [LibreSSL](https://www.libressl.org/), which was forked from OpenSSL 1.0 (and there were no plans of upgrading to OpenSSL 1.1.x API, AFAIK), so the API should be compatible. On the security side, you'll get a library, that has been reviewed and hardened, so there's less chance of undesired behaviour (that would be coming from the SSL library itself).

Comment: I don't think they are compatible in this case.

Comment: @TylerDurden why not? The idea behind LibreSSL was to be almost a drop-in replacement - do you have some more details?